# How minimize the app to a bubble with react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I need to minimize the app a bubble when I press the home button in react native.

Examples:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8K4m.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/n4DJZ.jpg

Someone can help me? Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this moment React native does not provide any library for floating head functionality. If you want to floating head you need to implement own by writing android and ios native code.

Without native code, it is not possible.

Answer (score 2):

Minimize app for React Native on Android And iOS.

https://github.com/FarzadMarius/react-native-minimize-app

```
npm i react-native-minimize --save
react-native link react-native-minimize
```

Comment: Thanks!! I solved with my own module. I needed to link the minimized app with a socket.io client and now it's ok.

Comment: @marcos-porto: Would be great, if you could share your solution. I've also searching for a Solution for something like that